# In Google Maps how do I search for an area and not a specific location

Tags: google-maps

How do I tell google maps that I'm looking for region and not a specific address.

When I search for "South Shore, qc" I get a bunch of businesses in the area.
But what I'm looking for is the outlined area of this region, as is returned when I search for
["Halifax, NS"](https://www.google.ca/maps/place/Halifax,+NS/@44.6462898,-63.702937,12z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x4b5a211407dbfac1:0x666be3a6438b2ddc!8m2!3d44.6475811!4d-63.5727683)

Comment: Bay area worked.  Southern shore worked for Newfoundland.  But this may have more to do with businesses having the term in their names.  [Google](https://patents.google.com/patent/CN102713906B/en) have a 2016 patent on region searches, so it must be a thing.